# Как запретить маршрутизацию OpenVPN?

Tags: windows-7, маршрутизация, настройка, openvpn

Исходные данные: Рабочий компьютер на Win7, находящийся в во внутренней сети, которая также подключена к интернету. В этой сети идет работа и доступ к приложениям и сервисам внутри организации и в других организациях(доступ есть только с нашего статичного IP-адреса в интернете).
Для реализации доступа клиент-клиент с другими устройствами(в основном, на 3G модемах с серыми IP) поднят OpenVPN-сервер на стороннем стабильном серваке с белым IP.
Суть вопроса: когда я подключаюсь к серверу OpenVPN, добрая одноименная тулза редактирует маршрутизацию компьютера, направляя весь трафик через сервер, из-за этого IP в интернете становится иным и доступ к сервисам других организаций пропадает. Можно ли запретить OpenVPN редактировать маршрутизацию и прописать просто постоянные маршруты в ROUTE вручную?

Answer (score 1):

Итак, я сам решил проблему. Спасибо, мне :).
Ответ:
В конфиге клиента был указан параметр "pull". Он и маршрутизировал всю сетку на VPN. Решением оказалось указать параметр "route-nopull" и прописать в конфиге route для доступа к другим машинам, подключенным к VPN. Теперь маршрутизация именно такая, какая мне и была нужна. В интернет-сети я остаюсь на свое работе, а с VPN имею доступ ко всем микрокомпьютерам организации.